# How can I add a font-awesome icon to a textarea?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a font-awesome icon to the top-left corner of a textarea. I tried using the following solution

```css
.text-box {
  margin: 30px auto;
  min-width: 480px;
}

.text-container {
  margin: 30px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.icon textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 17px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="text-box">
  <div class="text-container">
    <span class="text-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
    </span>
    <textarea rows="3">
          
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the alignment is off and the input text is vertically/horizontally centered.

Comment: Did you try the solution there? Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Questions should stand on their own. If the question you linked to is deleted then yours loses all value.

Comment: You have a complete example in the link you provided. Did you try to use it?

Comment: Great. Than update your question and add what you tried.

Comment: @ceejayoz this is not a duplicate

Comment: Sure it is. You want to do the same thing - the details vary only sightly.

Comment: As for your code you've added, the class `icon` doesn't exist in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```css
.text-box {
  margin: 30px auto;
  min-width: 480px;
}

.text-container {
  margin: 30px auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.text-container .text-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.text-container textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="text-box">
  <div class="text-container">
    <span class="text-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i>
    </span>
    <textarea rows="3">This is the text</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

> 1. Note the absolute position of **both** the textarea and the icon inside the container.
> 2. Note the background of the textarea (i removed it so you will see the icon behind it). Another option is the use `z-index` to move the icon to the front.

Comment: There is one problem with this implementation: if I have any html afterwards, the textarea runs over it. For example, if I have another input afterwards, you see this problem.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Try to play with the width/height of the container, it should fix this problem.