# How put icon inside textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea

i want to put this icon inside of my textarea in below image.

[image]

and here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" style="text-align: right;width: 100%;">
          <textarea row=100 cols=60
                    type="text"
                    id="input"
                    formControlName="txt"
                    placeholder="متن ...">
          </textarea>
          <span class="icon-user"></span>
        </div>
```

anyone knows how i must do for this problem ?

Comment: This has already been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764431/how-can-i-add-a-font-awesome-icon-to-a-textarea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the example: https://jsbin.com/laduyemewo/edit?html,css,output

The crucial changes here is to the set `position: relative;` to the parent `<div class="form-group">` and apply for `<span class="icon-user"></span>` - `position: absolute;` with a `bottom` and `left` properties based on your sizes.

Comment: One problem is when you are start resizing the textarea field

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using    `css` like this.
    `.icon-user {
         position:relative;
         top: -10px;
         left: -100px;
    }`
Adjust the values of    `top` and    `left` according to your needs. :)
Other way you could add    `position: absolute` to both the textarea and the icon.